# Is there a way to autosize columns in DataGrid .NET Compact Framework

Tags: .net, compact-framework, datagrid

I want to autofit columns to the content in cells. Also i want to add my headers to columns. Is there a way to achieve autosize?(i saw that column headers can be set with `DataGridTableStyle`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. I believe that "autosize" is *not* supported in the compact framework. You'll have to write your own code to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks..I'll fix the sizes then..It seems that CF is kinda not finished framework yet :(

Comment: Heh, well the excuse is package size. There is less code because "mobile devices have less space". They've been saying this for years though. An amusing assessment of CF 1.0 (which was shockingly limited, no stacktrace on exceptions for example) was: "The Compact Framework is just a thin wrapper around NotImplementedException."